# Connecting R to remote MySQL server - Can't Connect to server

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

Backstory, I would like to build shiny apps to give to some of our data collectors so they can review what has been collected. We currently house all of our data in a cloud based MySQL server. Ideally, I would like the shiny app to pull data directly from the MySQL server so it can be fully automated without any data pulls and up 24/7.

I have been trying to first just build the connection between R and MySQL using the RMySQL package and can't seem to get it working. I have set up a specific username/password for this connection that is read only(however I have also tried my regular username which has all privileges granted). This is the code I am running;

```
mydb=dbConnect(
   MySQL(), 
   user='myuser', 
   password='mypass', 
   dbname='vgtg', 
   host='ipaddress',
   port=3306,
   )
```

Obviously the 'ipaddress' of the server has been changed for the sake of posting here but it is a generic looking address like

```
  '192.168.1.1'
```

When I run the code above I get this error message;

```
Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 
 'ipaddress' (0)
```

I have tried looking for previous questions posted but none seem to be exactly this error message that I am receiving. It makes me think that for some reason RMySQL is looking locally for the server when it is actually a cloud based, remote, server.

Also, is there anything more I should set up server side to allow the connection? I do have a server admin to help out but I am not sure how familiar he is with R and likewise I am not particularly familiar with working with servers. He has opened port 3306 for me and is able to see my attempts to connect through the port.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct with the exception of

```
port=3306,
```

You need to drop the comma. That said, the error you received is unrelated to the syntax.

Without knowing the details of your setup, it is hard to diagnose. Where does the MySQL DB reside? For example, if it is on an AWS RDS instance, then the host isn't a standard IP address, it is something like this

```
mydb.cm1abc2v4mod.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

Assuming that the IP address you used is correct, then the problem is most likely on the server. You need to ensure that port 3306 is open to traffic. Otherwise, R will not be able to connect to the DB.

Comment: Ah right the extra comma ended up there when I was copy and pasting the code in here, my R version did not have it anyways. As for our server, I have been told it is a rackspace virtual server. Supposedly our server admin is able to see my log in attempts on port 3306 but does not know why it is not going through.